# Excel - VLOOKUP return based on partial match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets. Sheet 2 contains keywords. Sheet 1 contains some very long strings. Among the long strings, I need to find if there is match from the keyword on other page sheet 2.

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet 2

[image: Sheet2]

I used Wildcard but retuning #N/A

`=VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of keywords, and you want to return the one that matches, then try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(KeyWords,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(FIND(KeyWords,A2))*ROW(KeyWords),1)),"")
```

Comment: Hi @Ron,
Thanks a lot this formula works great if it matches the keyword it return the value if not it return as zero thank you

Comment: Hi @Ron Rosenfeld Need one help
above formula works great how to print it corresponding value to keyword
eg:
 above formula prints 3bscientific.de
i need to print its corresponding value
3bscientific.de     3b#

https://www.3bscientific.com/in/anatomy-set-life-sized    3b#

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using the `LOOKUP()` Function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH($D$1,A2),$D$1)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Try `SEARCH()` and `FILTER()`.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,A2))))
```

`TEXTJOIN()` for joining multiple keyword if any.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Harun24hr 
Filter function is not available in my excel could  you please give any alternative function

Comment: For older Excel use INDEX for same logic: `=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3,MATCH(1,N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,A2))),0))` and enter formula with `ctrl+shift+enter` this returns only the first match. If you need to return more this requires AGGREGATE

Comment: @Spidy Can you please check formula from P.b's comment.

Comment: @Harun24hr 
p.b formula returning to #N/A in sheet 1 B2 results
and with ctrl+shift+enter result returning 0

Comment: Sorry, the index needs updated to column A

Comment: The one shown by @P.b should also work for you unless you have something else.

Comment: Thank you  @P.b i updated the formula to column A getting expected output

Comment: Hi @Harun24hr , Thanks for the formula. I used in Google sheets where filter function is available and its working great! Getting expected results. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome Merry XMATCH* (formula available in newer Excel)